# Node.js Express Sessions re-save session info to store after deleted from store

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, session-cookies, express-session

I think I just don't understand how express sessions work, or maybe sessions altogether.  I'm using Express MySQL Express for the store with basic setup for both:

```
app.use(session({
  key:config.dev.sessionOpts.key,
  secret:config.dev.sessionOpts.secret,
  store:sessionStore,
  resave:true,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  cookie: {
    sameSite:'strict',
    path:'/',
    maxAge: null,
    httpOnly:true,
    secure:false
  }
}));
```

And the MySQL store:

```
'mysqlStore': {
  host:'localhost',
  user:'users',
  password:'',
  database:'testDB',
  clearExpired:true,
  checkExpirationInterval:900000
}
```

The sessions are stored in the sessions table, they persist while using the site.  If I delete the entry from the DB, I can still see the cookie in the browser console and the cookie gets sent on the next request.  What I don't understand is that a new session gets created and entered into the DB.  How can I revert back to that session from the cookie and re-insert back into the DB?

Reason for this question is the following scenario. The DB 'expires' column in the DB gets set to +1 day.  When a user logs in, I want to extend this session for 30 days.  If the user doesn't visit the site for more than 1 day, doesn't close their browser, they will come back with the old session cookie but the DB entry will have been deleted.  A new session will be created and the persistent login info will be lost.  Any advice?

Comment: If the session data has been removed from the database, you can't reconstruct it (apart from restoring from a backup database). The cookie only contains a unique session id, it doesn't contain any actual session _information_ that can be used to reconstruct it.

Comment: @robertklep When I log `req.session.id` and `req.session.cookie` I see the same information that has been saved to the DB columns (session_id, data).  Including any extra variables which I have set.  So the cookie contains all of the information which COULD be inserted back into the table.

Comment: @robertklep nevermind...the log shows the data from the new session...I guess the other part of the question is if there is a way to extend the "expires" column in the DB when the user logs in?